# apple touch icon svg support

Tags: svg, apple-touch-icon

Is it possible (or soon supported) to replace all touch-icon's with a single SVG?

So, instead of;

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144.png">
```

... just a single;

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.svg">
```

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately iOS doesn't support SVG icons at the moment. And it will probably not have support soon. Also android doesn't support it.

**Update:**
It looks like Safari is starting to support SVG favicons

See:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg

To add a svg icon for pinned tabs within Safari you need to add:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="website_icon.svg" color="red">
```

Comment: How would I add this?

Comment: This example only works with pinned tabs in Safari on Mac. There is no support for pinned tabs on iOS and this is not used for the touch icon either.